# Is there a way to specify which workspace to open on next launch?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have an automated script that will install VS Code for our developers and set up a workspace for them, but I don't see a way to specify in a config file which workspace file should be opened when they launch the application for the first time? Optimally it would launch right into where they need to be on first open and we could forgo a "find this workspace file on your disk and double click it" since new users might not even be familiar with what a workspace is.

It would be great to have a user setting such as "default workspace" that would auto launch when there is no recent workspace:

```
{
 "workbench.defaultWorkspace": "/code/main.code-workspace",
}
```

Is there any way to modify what the launch behavior is without opening the app?

Comment: As an option you can create a shortcut which will run VS Code and pass the workspace as an argument. You can read more at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-files-and-folders

Comment: create a shortcut on the desktop that will give the folder or workspace as argument to vsc.exe and it will open there.